# converting int to ascii and back with java don't work correct

Tags: java, text-files, ascii

I want to convert int to ascii. But i get not the right value, when i convert from ascii to int.

```
int calc=4;
writer.write(calc-127+"="+(char)calc+"="+ (Character.getNumericValue((char)calc)-127)+
System.lineSeparator());
```

=>

```
15= =-128
4=f=-128
-5=z=-92
```

Comment: By "int to ascii" you mean from `int` to `char` right?

Comment: yes, i want to save a waveform in a .txt file from -127 to 127 => 0 to 255 => chars. Later i want to reconvert:  chars => 0 to 255 => -127 to 127

Answer (score 0):

1) int to char:`int  n = 1;
      char ch = （char）(n + '0');`

2) char to int:
     `char ch = '9';
      int n = int(ch) - int('0');`

Comment: when i try this i get an unexpected type.

Answer (score 0):

Replace char(int), which just changes the tripe but doesn't make it ascii with String.valuOfInt(int)